# How to fix MS Teams "Something Went Wrong" error when sideloading bot?

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I used to have a bot using the default framework provided by Visual Studio Code but it has seemingly stopped working for no reason I have determined as of yet.
I have created a new bot and registration through Visual Studio Code using the bare bones provided framework with no success. When I try to sideload the bot I get the error message `Something went wrong. For more information go to aka.ms/teamsdocs`. The url `aka.ms/teamsdocs` does not appear to exist. I'm not sure whether this is caused by a registration issue or otherwise, but since recently any and all bots I create have the same error.

[MS Teams Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEVjQ.png)

Comment: Had something similar. In my case I made a mistake in the manifest (wrong AppiD)
I would suggest you add your manifest (and strip all sensitive parts) so people can look at it.

Comment: @Seer, Could you please let us know still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

**Posting the Answer for better knowledge**

**Copying from @Hessel comments**

Had something similar. In my case I made a mistake in the manifest (wrong AppiD) I would suggest you add your manifest (and strip all sensitive parts) so people can look at it.